# Why is a 2D vector array not just a 1D array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I don't have a specific code example here but what is the difference in the two arrays resulting from the DIM statements below:

```
Sub Diff1D2D()
Dim arr1D(500)
Dim arr2D(500, 1)
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 500
    arr1D(i) = i
    arr2D(i, 1) = i
    Debug.Print arr1D(i), arr2D(i, 1)
Next I
end sub
```

The trivial results are:

1             1

...           ...

497           497

498           498

499           499

500           500

Besides the obvious answer that arr1D has only 1 dimension (is it a column or a row nobody knows) and arr2D has 2 dimensions (500 rows and only 1 column), what are the more esoteric notions?

Many sample pieces of code out on the innerwebs are limited to taking 1D arrays as arguments. So if I read a 1 column range of data from a worksheet (automatically creates a 2D array of (n X 1), then if I'm limited to a 1D array for some call to another function or sub, I have to convert the 2D array to 1D yet it contains the exact same data.

Comment: As a data range can indeed be a 2D array, the most general data structure is used. Otherwise, special overloads of the functions should coexist, accepting row or column vectors, tripling the number of functions.

Comment: Thanks Yves, I think I understand.

Comment: Thanks Yves, I think I understand. Might the conclusion be that functions that can only tolerate and/or produce 1D arrays are less robust than functions that can handle multi-dimension arrays with arguments specifying the index of the column or row to be processed?

Comment: FWIW - In your sample code, `arr1D` contains 501 elements, and `arr2D` contains 1002 elements.  (You haven't specified that the lower bound of the two arrays is 1, so it has defaulted to `Dim arr1D(0 To 500)` and `Dim arr2D(0 To 500, 0 To 1)`.)

Comment: @farmerandy: I don't see any connection with robustness.

Comment: @ YowE3K The Option Base 1 statement is missing.

Comment: Perhaps versatility was the more appropriate word.